# how to keep server-side ReadTimeoutHandler in Netty from firing while server is preparing the response?

Tags: netty

since a server-side ReadTimeoutHandler in Netty doesn't know **why** the client isn't writing any data, it may happen that it throws a ReadTimeoutException while the server is still working on preparing a response to a received client request (i.e., during a time when the client simply doesn't write anything because it is still waiting for the server's reply).

Which is the best practice to handle such a situation? I'm currently thinking of

- Keeping a flag within my handler that tells the server to ignore a read timeout while it is preparing a response,
- Removing the ReadTimeoutHandler from the pipeline while the server is preparing a response, and re-adding it afterwards or
- Writing my own version of ReadTimeoutHandler that can be turned on and off on a per-channel basis.

Is there a proposed approach for handling this in Netty?

Answer (score 0):

I would just ignore the timeout if its fired and its expected.. An other way which I also did before is to add and remove the handler from the pipeline on the fly

Comment: Though one problem with ignoring the timeout is that, once it is ignored, it won't be fired again, even after the server goes on to listen to the client again.